# Find ∂f/∂$\vec{u}$ at (1, 0), where $\vec{u} = 2\vec{i}+\vec{j}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $$f(x, y, z) = xe^{y+z^2}$$ where $z = z(x, y)$ is itself implicitly a function of x and y given by
$z + e^z = x + 2y$.

Find ∂f/∂$\vec{u}$ at (1, 0), where $\vec{u} = 2\vec{i}+\vec{j}$

We can think of f as a function of just x and y. How would I determine ∂f/∂$\vec{u}$? Would I have to use some sort of change of variables? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are given the identity
$$Z(x,y) + \exp Z(x,y) = x + 2y \tag{1}$$
From which, applying $\partial/\partial x$ to both sides and using the "chain rule",
$$\frac{\partial Z}{\partial x}(x,y) + \exp Z(x,y) \frac{\partial Z}{\partial x} (x,y) = 1 $$
leading to
$$\frac{\partial Z}{\partial x}(x,y) = \frac{1}{1 + \exp Z(x,y)} \tag{2a}$$
Similarly
$$\frac{\partial Z}{\partial y}(x,y) = \frac{2}{1 + \exp Z(x,y)} \tag{2b}$$

Can you go on from this point? If not, see below.

---

**Chain rule.** I'll use a more formal notation in order to minimize hand-waviness. This might confuse you, but I am sure that quick consultation of your reference textbook will settle all doubts.

You may view your $f$ as the composition of a function $\mathbf w : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^3$ taking $(x,y) \mapsto (x,y,Z(x,y))$ and a function $\mu : \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R$ taking $(a,b,c) \mapsto a \exp(b + c^2)$. Notice in particular that $\partial w_1 / \partial x = 1$, $\partial w_2 / \partial y = 1$, $\partial w_1 / \partial y = 0$, $\partial w_2 / \partial x = 0$, $\partial w_3 / \partial x = \partial Z / \partial x$, and $\partial w_3 / \partial y = \partial Z / \partial y$.

Then, by the multivariable "chain rule", exploiting equation $\mathrm{(2a)}$,

$$\begin{split}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) &= \frac{\partial \mu}{\partial a}(\mathbf w(x,y))\frac{\partial w_1}{\partial x}(x,y) + \frac{\partial \mu}{\partial b}(\mathbf w(x,y))\frac{\partial w_2}{\partial x}(x,y) + \frac{\partial \mu}{\partial c}(\mathbf w(x,y))\frac{\partial w_3}{\partial x}(x,y) \\
&= \exp(y + Z(x,y)^2) + 2xZ(x,y)\exp(y+Z(x,y)^2)\left(\frac{1}{1 + \exp Z(x,y)}\right) \\
&= \exp(y + Z(x,y)^2) \left(\frac{1 + 2xZ(x,y)}{1 + \exp Z(x,y)}\right) 
\end{split} \tag{3a}$$

and similarly, exploiting equation $\mathrm{(2b)}$,

$$\begin{split}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y) &= \frac{\partial \mu}{\partial a}(\mathbf w(x,y))\frac{\partial w_1}{\partial y}(x,y) + \frac{\partial \mu}{\partial b}(\mathbf w(x,y))\frac{\partial w_2}{\partial y}(x,y) + \frac{\partial \mu}{\partial c}(\mathbf w(x,y))\frac{\partial w_3}{\partial y}(x,y) \\
&= x\exp(y + Z(x,y)^2) + 2xZ(x,y)\exp(y+Z(x,y)^2)\left(\frac{2}{1 + \exp Z(x,y)}\right)\\
&= \exp(y + Z(x,y)^2)\left(\frac{x + 4xZ(x,y)}{1 + \exp Z(x,y)}\right)
\end{split}\tag{3b}$$

modulo careless mistakes. At this point you need only know how to take directional derivatives. If you have any doubt, check below.

---

**Directional derivative.** You may remember that the Jacobian of $f$ at $(x,y)$ is the matrix
$$ Jf(x,y) \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) & \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y) \end{bmatrix} $$
(which you could see as the transpose of the gradient of $f$ at $(x,y)$) and that the directional derivative of $f$ along a unit vector $\mathbf v$ at $(x,y)$ is defined to be
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf v}(x,y) = Jf(x,y) \mathbf v $$
In your case, $\mathbf v = \frac{1}{\sqrt 5}\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$, so you just end up with
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf v}(x,y) = \frac{2}{\sqrt 5}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) + \frac{1}{\sqrt 5}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y) \tag{4}$$

If you substitute into $(4)$ the expressions for the partials of $f$ that were found in $\mathrm{(3a)}$ and $\mathrm{(3b)}$ above, you have solved the exercise at all points $(x,y)$.

---

**Final step.** To solve the problem for $(x,y) = (1,0)$, one needs to know the value $t := Z(1,0)$. Identity $(1)$ tells us that such number $t$ would satisfy
$$t + e^t = 1 $$
which is only possible when $t = 0$. (To see this, try drawing the graph for $t$ and the graph for $1-e^t$.) So $Z(1,0) = 0$. Substituting this into equation $(4)$, along with $x = 1$ and $y = 0$, leads to the answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. This really cleared things up. Also, where are the expressions for the partials of f that I need to substitute in to solve?

Comment: I have numbered the relevant equations to ease referencing.

Comment: Okay. But that wouldn't give me an exact answer, would it? I think the problem requires a unique answer.

Comment: Once you've solved for a general point $(x,y)$, you have also solved for $(1,0)$ – just plug in. The only slightly non-trivial part about this is finding the value $Z(1,0)$.

Comment: Oh okay. And how would i find z(1,0)?

Comment: Can you please show the computation? I'm still kinda confused.

Comment: Fine. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up with 3/2*$5^{1/2}$